# SMTP Implicit TLS and Explicit TLS using Indy 10.6.2.5341 in Delphi

Tags: delphi, indy

A bit of an odd one here, when setting "UseTLS" to utUseExplicitTLS and then connecting to a mail server on its Implicit TLS port, the first attempt allows the connection and sends the email, subsequent attempts on that port correctly fail.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to avoid the false positive on the initial connect and send.

The check is to handle that non-standard ports may be getting used for a user's mail server. Pretty much all examples I've seen assume that the correct information will always be provided.

Below is the code portion that handles it (excluding error logging):

```
function SendTestEmail(EmailAddress: String): Boolean;
var
  EmailMessage: TidMessage;
begin
  IdSMTPEmail.AuthType := satDefault
  IdSMTPEmail.Username := ...;
  IdSMTPEmail.Password := ...;
  IdSMTPEmail.Port := 465;

  IdSMTPEmail.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTPEmail);
  IdSMTPEmail.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdSMTPEmail.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  try
    // Connect
    IdSMTPEmail.Connect('smtp.gmail.com');

    try
      // Create
      EmailMessage := TidMessage.Create(nil);

      try
        // Set values
        EmailMessage.Body.Add('Test Email');
        EmailMessage.Subject := 'Test Email';

        // Set sender details
        EmailMessage.From.Address := 'test@test.com';
        EmailMessage.From.Name := 'SSL Test';

        // Set recipient
        EmailMessage.Recipients.Add.Address := EmailAddress;

        try
          // Send message
          IdSMTPEmail.Send(EmailMessage);

        except
          // Exception
          on E: EIdSMTPReplyError do
          begin
            // Result
            Result := False;
          end;
        end;

      finally
        // Free email
        EmailMessage.Free;
      end;

    finally
      // Disconnect
      IdSMTPEmail.Disconnect;
    end;

  except
    // Exception
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      IdSMTPEmail.Disconnect;
      // Result
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What you describe is not possible. The implicit TLS port requires a TLS handshake be initiated immediately upon connect and be fully completed before the SMTP greeting can then be sent. `utUseExplicitTLS` does not send a handshake upon connect, so `Connect()` will block waiting for a greeting that is never sent, until the server disconnects or the `ReadTimeout` elapses, whichever occurs first. Either way, the calling code will not be able to get far enough to send any emails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what you've said is the behaviour that I was expecting and was stunned when the above worked for the first attempt. As a check, I had Wireshark running at the same time and it showed success on the first attempts (email was also received) but subsequent attempts would timeout and nothing was picked up by Wireshark.

Comment: what you say is simply not possible on an **implicit TLS** port. The TLS handshake is *required*. You were most likely connected to a *non-implicit* port on the first attempt, and then connected to an *implicit* port on subsequent attempts. Use Wireshark to verify the port used on each connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't end up seeing your response until now, but I'll post what appears to have fixed it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code, correctly failed on all attempts of trying to email to port 465.

I don't even pretend to understand why this works but my original didn't.

```
function SendTestEmail(EmailAddress: String): Boolean;
var
  EmailMessage: TidMessage;
  IdSSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  IdSMTPEmail.AuthType := satDefault;

  IdSSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  IdSSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;

  IdSMTPEmail.IOHandler := IdSSLHandler;
  IdSMTPEmail.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

  IdSMTPEmail.Username := ...;
  IdSMTPEmail.Password := ...;
  IdSMTPEmail.Port := 465;

  try
    // Connect
    IdSMTPEmail.Connect('smtp.gmail.com');

    try
      // Create
      EmailMessage := TidMessage.Create(nil);

      try
        // Set values
        EmailMessage.Body.Add('Test Email');
        EmailMessage.Subject := 'Test Email';

        // Set sender details
        EmailMessage.From.Address := 'test@test.com';
        EmailMessage.From.Name := 'SSL Test';

        // Set recipient
        EmailMessage.Recipients.Add.Address := EmailAddress;

        try
          // Send message
          IdSMTPEmail.Send(EmailMessage);

        except
          // Exception
          on E: EIdSMTPReplyError do
          begin
            // Result
            Result := False;
          end;
        end;

      finally
        // Free email
        EmailMessage.Free;
      end;

    finally
      // Disconnect
      IdSMTPEmail.Disconnect;
    end;

  except
    // Exception
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      IdSMTPEmail.Disconnect;
      // Result
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```